# Java Script Regular expression for number format not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the input from the user as 888-999-6666..i.e. 3 numbers then a '-' then 3 numbers then again '-' and finally 4 numbers.
I am using the following regular expression in my JavaScript.

```
     var num1=/^[0-9]{3}+-[0-9]{3}+-[0-9]{3}$/;
  if(!(form.num.value.match(num1)))
           {
           alert("Number cannot be left empty");
           return false;
           }
```

But its not working.
If I use `var num1=/^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]$/;`   then it wants at least two '-' but no restriction on the numbers.

How can i get the RE as my requirement? And why is the above code not working?

Comment: `var num1=/^[0-9]{3}+-[0-9]{3}+-[0-9]{3}$/;` typo near last symbol class? Did you mean `{4}`?

Comment: @SergeyLagutin `+` after `{}` acts like a possessive quantifier which was supported by php but js won't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `+` symbol which are present just after to the repetition quantifier `{}` . And replace `[0-9]{3}` at the last with `[0-9]{4}`, so that it would allow exactly 4 digits after the last `-` symbol.

```
var num1=/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nR7cC4/1)

You could also write `[0-9]` as `\d`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be:

```
var num1=/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;
```

There is an extra `+` after number range in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Issue in your regex.check below example.

```js
var num='888-999-6668';
var num1=/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;
  if(!(num.match(num1)))
   {
      alert("Number cannot be left empty");
   }else{
      alert("Match");
   }
```

In your example there is extra + symbole after {3}, which generate issue here. so i removed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num1=/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
```

I think this will work for you.
The rest of your code will be the same.